# sql function for combine 2 by 2 rows (Oracle db)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (in Oracle database) like:

```
myid | data1 | data2 | data3
1    'a'     'b'     'c'
1    'd'     'e'     'f'
1    'g'     'h'     'i'
2    'j'     'j'     'j'
2    'j'     'j'     'j'
3    'k'     'k'     'k'
```

I have a task to combine them by myid, but only 2 rows at a time. So the exit here should be:

```
1 'abcdef'
1 'ghi'
2 'jjjjjj'
3 'kkk'
```

One id can have many rows..if there are `11 rows` for one id, function should return `6 rows` for that id `(1+2, 3+4, 5+6, 7+8, 9+10, 11)`.

function should probably look like `getCombinedRowsForId(Id number)` or maybe even `getCombinedRows()` and it should return a whole table of data.

any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you combine the "last" two rows?OR does it matter which 2 rows?

Comment: nice editing..thanks. will try to learn something from it.

Comment: Mihai - it doesn't matter which 2 rows. it can be (row1+row3 as returnRow1, row2+row11 as returnRow2, ..., row9 as returnRow6). Just can't be duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT myid,
  LISTAGG(data,'') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY rank)
FROM
  (SELECT myid,
    data1||data2||data3  AS data,
    row_number() over (order by 1) AS rank,
    CASE MOD((row_number() over (partition by myid order by 1)),2)
      WHEN 1
      THEN row_number() over (partition by myid order by 1)
      ELSE row_number() over (partition by myid order by 1) -1
    END AS sub_rank
  FROM your_table
  )
GROUP BY myid, sub_rank;
```

it generates a view first like

```
      MYID DATA                       RANK   SUB_RANK
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
         1 abb                           1          1
         1 dee                           2          1
         1 ghh                           3          3
         2 jjj                           4          1
         2 jjj                           5          1
         3 kkk                           6          1
```

And then group using myid,subrank AND `LISTAGG()` concats the rows in the group together.

**Note:** Works with Oracle 11g + only

Comment: To be precise: that requires 11g **Release 2** (aka 11.2). `listagg()` is not available in 11.1